# Python-Install scikits.talkbox to Anaconda in Windows 8

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, anaconda

I am using **Python 2.7** and **Anaconda2**. I tried to install it using

> conda

but Anaconda cloud only has

> scikits.talkbox

for *linux 64 channel*.

but I want this toolbox for signal processing.

How can I install it in **Anaconda**?

Answer (score 0):

You can pip it on anaconda console:

```
pip install --user scikits.talkbox
```

It may ask for installing Visual C++ for python, it is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).